# facing issue while exporting java script array to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, export-to-excel

I am able to export javascript array to csv,bu facing when changed the file extension to xslx.

Please let me know what could be the issue in changing the extension to xslx.

please find code snippet working for csv and not for xslx.

```
function Export2Excel(data) {
        var tempCSVNumber = 0;

        var CSVData = [];
        var str = '';
         $("#ddlFilterlist > option").each(function () {
                str += '"' + this.value + '",';
        });

        CSVData.push(str);

        for (var i = tempCSVNumber; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
            var item = data[i];
            var csvVal = '';
            var hString = str .substring(0, str .length - 1);
            result = hString
                .split(',')
                .map(key => {
                    var val = item[key.toUpperCase()
                        .replace(/"/g, '')];
                     csvVal += '"' + val + '",';
                     return csvVal;
                })

            CSVData.push(csvVal);
        }


            var CSVFileName = 'Test.xlsx';


        var csvData = CSVData.join("\n");
        if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {

                blob = new Blob([csvData], {
                    //"type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
                    //"type": "application/octet-stream;" 
                    //"type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                    //"type":"application/vnd.ms-excel;"
                    "type": "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;"
                    //data: attachment / xlsx
                });

            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, CSVFileName);
            }
        }
        else {

                var blob = new Blob([csvData],
                    //{ type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
                    //{ type: "application/octet-stream" });
                   // { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8;' });
                   // { type: "data:attachment/xlsx;" });
                { type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        }

            var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", csvUrl);
            link.setAttribute("download", CSVFileName);
            link.setAttribute("target", '_blank');
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            if (link.click !== undefined)
                link.click();
            else if (document.createEvent) {
                var eventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                eventObj.initEvent('click', true, true);
                link.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
            }
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }

    }
```

I tried changing with different types for blob data,but its not working.

here is the error getting while trying to open the downloaded xslx file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with passing an object array. It worked for me. As rows i send the selected object array list.

```
exportToCsv(filename: string, rows: object[]) {
    if (!rows || !rows.length) {
      return;
    }
    const separator = ',';
    const keys = Object.keys(rows[0]);
    const csvData =
      keys.join(separator) +
      '\n' +
      rows.map((row: any) => {
        return keys.map(k => {
          let cell = row[k] === null || row[k] === undefined ? '' : row[k];
          cell = cell instanceof Date
            ? cell.toLocaleString()
            : cell.toString().replace(/"/g, '""');
          if (cell.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0) {
            cell = `"${cell}"`;
          }
          return cell;
        }).join(separator);
      }).join('\n');

    const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      if (link.download !== undefined) {
        // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.setAttribute('href', url);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Itried with above code and its not working with filename :text.xslx. I am looking for pure javascript function as some of the functions(row:any and filename:) are not supported when i copied yours.

Comment: this is how i passed the parameters"this.contactExportHelper.exportToCsv(
      'ExportContacts.csv',
      dataArray
    );"here dataArray is my object array. actually i'm using typescript.